# Как сделать запросы правильно в laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть страница с пятью секциями. В каждой секции мне из БД нужно вывести заголовок и текст не обарачивая при этом всю секцию в foreach.
Как сделать скрипт универсальным и правильным?

Сейчас работает так:

```
public function section()
{
    $section = Section::whereIn('section', ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5'])->get();

    $s1 = $section->where('section','=','s1');
    $s2 = $section->where('section','=','s2');
    $s3 = $section->where('section','=','s3');
    $s4 = $section->where('section','=','s4');
    $s5 = $section->where('section','=','s5');

    return view('index', [
        's1' => $s1, 
        's2' => $s2, 
        's3' => $s3, 
        's4' => $s4, 
        's5' => $s5
    ]);
}
```

В шаблоне вывожу примерно так:

```
<section id="one">
    @foreach ($s1 as $el) {{ $el->title }} @endforeach
</section>

<section id="two">
    @foreach ($s2 as $el) {{ $el->title }} @endforeach
</section>

<section id="three">
    @foreach ($s3 as $el) {{ $el->title }} @endforeach
</section>
```

Comment: Вам реализация не нравится или не верно работает код?

Comment: @InDevX мне не нравится реализация

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод [`keyBy()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-keyby) заполнит ключи, элементов коллекции, указанным свойством.

```
public function section()
{
    $sections = Section::whereIn('section', ['s1', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5'])->get()->keyBy('section');


    return view('index', compact('sections'));
}
```

Получить доступ к нужному элементу можно с помощью метода `get()` или `$sections['s1']`

```
<section id="one">
    {{ $sections->get('s1')->title }}
</section>

<section id="two">
    {{ $sections->get('s2')->title }}
</section>

<section id="three">
    {{ $$sections->get('s3')->title }}
</section>
```

Comment: пишет rying to get property 'title' of non-object

Comment: @hellokitViki Что у вас в переменной `$sections`?

Comment: ну всё как в вашем примере

Comment: @hellokitViki сделайте `dd` и посмотрите, что у вас там. По возможности, сделайте скрин и прикрепите его сюда. Ошибка говорит, что вы пытаетесь получить свойство  **title** у не обьекта.

Comment: добавила в вопрос, что выдало

Comment: @hellokitViki Так, стоп. Свойство `title`. Если секция содержит заголовок. Зачем `foreach`? Исправил пример.